# Why is there a subjective warning for questions on a meta-discussion site?

Tags: bug, status-completed

When I tried to post my [last question on etiquette](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/893/whats-the-etiquette-for-reusing-your-answers), I got this warning:

> The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed.

If the warning shouldn't appear anywhere, you'd think Meta Programmers.SE would be it.

Comment: Link to the question (if it still exists)?

Comment: Voting to close as this does not meet enough of our six subjective guidelines .. (ducks)

Comment: I had this too when writing this question: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/964/7167

Answer (score 2):

While I don't know when it was fixed, this apparently no longer occurs, so: [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)!